# Cocos2d-x ios Application loader stuck authenticating with the itunes store

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

We have been trying to submit Game (Developed using Cocos2d-x)to the iTunes store using Application Loader for five days and keep getting stuck at the "Authenticating with the iTunes store" step.
We have read many forums (including stack-overflow) and tried what was suggested:

1) Try Uploading using two Instances of Application Loader.
2) The Mostly Occurring issue if Icon.png in info.plist have been resolved
3) Creating New Provisioning Profile and Revocation of Developer Certificate.
4) We also have tried by Let Application Loader for Full Night around 18 Hours.

But Now we surrendered on this need Some Expert Help.

Answer (score 0):

Go ask Apple for help. You get assistance as part of your developer membership. http://developer.apple.com